# Swift: Messages outside the application on silent notification

Tags: swift, background, notifications, uialertview

My application uses Silent notifications and I'm looking for a way to show message on the screen when notification is received and the application is in background. Something like alert on the screen with custom visibility duration and the text must be a result from some calculations of the application. Is there a way to achieve this? I tried with notifications, but I can't set the time to be visible and I cant set the text from within the device. Also when notification is received my app doesn't appear on the screen until user interaction with the notification message. Thats why I'm looking for some alternative way to do it. Something like on the image below. Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Edit: Ok ... It could also be enough if I can edit the alert of the notification on the device, before it is shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you can have alerts with custom text using UILocalNotifications.

You said "I tried with notifications, but I can't set the time to be visible and I cant set the text from within the device"

However you can specify a date/time to fire:

```
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate
```

And you can set the notification content too:

```
localNotification.alertBody = "Some text \(SomeVariable)"
```

However the "custom visibility duration" is not possible as far as I have seen.

What more would you want to accomplish?

Comment: All you said is true, but the problem was that I needed Remote notifications, from server, with text set from the device itself (not from the server). The server sends me a code and using that code I have to show a message to the user, but personalised for its current profile (one of many) saved on the device. I also needed to show the message for a custom time period. However, I ended up with a silent remote notification which sets local remote notification with the desired message, but the problem with visibility period still exists.